# trying to convert promise-queue example to nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, queue, bluebird

I trying to convert this [promise-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-queue) in sample JQuery [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RVuEU/1/) to Nodejs as it fits my requirement. I am encountering below issues, this is my code and error

```
"TypeError: dfd.promise is not a function"
    return dfd.promise();
```

What i am trying to code is just another rate-limiter, i can make only 3 requests per second and requests are all promises and i want to put all my requests in a queue and once it resolves or rejects only then next waiting request in queue can start processing. Bluebird queue actions the item in the queue in blocks. What i am trying to workout looks exactly as in the earlier [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128109/bluebird-queue-concurrency-in-promise-queues-not-working-as-expected) link. I am just starting and i am stuck in the first part itself.

```
var Queue = require("promise-queue");
var Promise = require("bluebird");

var maxConcurrent = 1;
//var maxQueue = Infinity;
var queue = new Queue(maxConcurrent, 2);

// Or just Queue.configure(window.Promise);
Queue.configure(function (handler) {
    var dfd = Promise.defer();
    try {
        handler(dfd.resolve, dfd.reject, dfd.progress);
    } catch (e) {
        dfd.reject(e);
    }
    return dfd.promise();
});

// max concurrent - 1
// max queue - 2
var id = 0;

function processSomethingHeavy() {
    id++;
    var dfd = Promise.defer();
    var loading = id;    
    setTimeout(dfd.resolve, 4000, loading);    
    return dfd.promise();
}

function status() {
    console.log('Pending ' + queue.pendingPromises + '/' + queue.maxPendingPromises + ' Queued ' + queue.queue.length + '/' + queue.maxQueuedPromises);
}

    queue.add(processSomethingHeavy)
    .then(function (loading) {
        status();
        console.log('loading',loading);
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('error',err);
    });

    queue.add(processSomethingHeavy)
    .then(function (loading) {
        status();
        console.log('loading',loading);
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('error',err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want to stop using `deferred` and start using `Promise`.

Given that you are running your code in `nodejs`, [Promises](https://node.green/#ES2015-built-ins-Promise) should be natively supported so there is no need for Bluebird.

According promise-queue's [docs](https://github.com/promise-queue/promise-queue#configure-queue):

> By default Queue tries to use global Promises, but you can specify your own promises.

So you can skip this step completely as you'll have Promises natively.

"Finally" you can then update `processSomethingHeavy` to use a `Promise`.

```
function processSomethingHeavy() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var loading = ++id;    
        setTimeout(resolve, 4000, loading);
    });
}
```

Comment: You are right, at that time i may have been overthinking.